# R Visuals not loading in Power BI Services

Tags: r, powerbi, visualization

I am having a nightmare with my R visuals in PBI Services, the visual worked fine for the last 9 months and come yesterday they are no longer rendering in PBI Service. I have checked to see if the R packages are with the PBI library and tick. below is the package list. I have updated Cran R from 3.6.1 to 3.6.2

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

cannot see the wood for the trees, help kindly please. Not sure if this could be something to do with the gateway and or tenant or something else.

Comment: you really need to re-word the question and refrain from vernacular verbiage, because its making no sense.. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and learn how to create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks for the feedback, noted for future posts. I have managed to get a resolution to the issue, the issue is with Premium Capacity and Microsoft product end.

not sure how to move forward with the question now. Assistance appreciated from the community.